# ping command not showing in Heroku stack

Tags: python, ubuntu, heroku, ping

There was no ping command in Heroku default stack (Using Ubuntu 20.04). I have installed the package 'iputils-ping' using buildpack, however it's not showing 'command not found'. also tried with links to specific .deb files in Aptfile of buildpack.

The deploy logs showing it's installed however after completion, getting command not found. Is there anyway I can install that package and use the ping command in my python script to deploy.

```
$ git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 360 bytes | 360.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
remote:        2. heroku-community/apt
remote:        3. heroku/python
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Detected Aptfile or Stack changes, flushing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
remote:        Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
remote:        Hit:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
remote:        Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for iputils-ping
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          iputils-ping
remote:        0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 40.1 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 108 kB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 iputils-ping amd64 3:20190709-3 [40.1 kB]
remote:        Fetched 40.1 kB in 0s (151 kB/s)
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Fetching http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iputils/iputils-ping_20210202-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing iputils-ping_20210202-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing iputils-ping_3%3a20190709-3_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Apt app detected
remote: -----> Reusing cache
remote: -----> Updating apt caches
remote:        Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
remote:        Hit:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease
remote:        Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
remote:        Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote: -----> Fetching .debs for iputils-ping
remote:        Reading package lists...
remote:        Building dependency tree...
remote:        The following NEW packages will be installed:
remote:          iputils-ping
remote:        0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
remote:        Need to get 0 B/40.1 kB of archives.
remote:        After this operation, 108 kB of additional disk space will be used.
remote:        Download complete and in download only mode
remote: -----> Fetching http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iputils/iputils-ping_20210202-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing iputils-ping_20210202-1_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Installing iputils-ping_3%3a20190709-3_amd64.deb
remote: -----> Writing profile script
remote: -----> Rewrite package-config files
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the same version as the last build: python-3.9.5
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
remote: -----> Using cached install of python-3.9.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
```

Comment: Why do you have two different Apt buildpacks configured?

Comment: And what makes you think that package wasn't properly installed? The output here suggests that the installation succeeded.

Comment: Why do you have two different Apt buildpacks configured?  >> First I have added the package name, that's not worked. then added the .deb URL from Ubuntu website that's too not worked. 

yes, the log stating that it's installed. however when I run the command, it's showing command not found. checked using `which ping`, that's not shown anything.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. The output says "Using buildpacks" and then lists _three_ buildpacks, including both `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt` and `heroku-community/apt`. Why are you trying to use _two_ Apt buildpacks?

Comment: "however when I run the command, it's showing command not found"—how are you trying to run the command?

Answer (score 0):

It's installed, however I am unable to use this command in my Python program since 'ping' command requires root privilege to execute that Heroku not allowing :(

```
~ $ which ping
/bin/ping
~ $
```